# C# A question about the lambda expression as a method parameter

Tags: c#, lambda

At the page `code.google.com/p/fakeiteasy/` I've noticed the line:

```
A.CallTo(() => shop.GetTopSellingCandy()).Returns(lollipop);
```

so the question is - how to pass a lambda expression as a method parameter ?

Comment: Uhm? I might be missing something (a lambda expression has a valid name-able static type, except when dealing with those out-of-place 'new {}' constructs) -- what have you tried? Hint: consider `Func<...>` in many cases.

Answer (score 5):

This function takes a parameter of type `Func<T>` (A normal delegate with a generic parameter), or, more likely, `Expression<Func<T>>` (an [expression tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)).

The function itself probably has a generic parameter which is inferred from the method passed.

By taking an expression tree, the function is able to inspect the code inside the expression and see what it does.

Comment: Yup, that's right, FakeItEasy inspects the expression tree to get the instance a method is called on and which method (and with what parameters) is called on that instance.

Answer (score 2):

The code you've given is doing exactly that - passing a lambda expression as a paramter to a method call.

Answer (score 0):

`CallTo` might have the signature 'CallTo(Action action)'. So lambda is passed as a delegate